# What is "Query Pileup" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My team is running a test on MySQL database and I noticed that MySQL Enterprise Monitor shows a **Query Pileup alert**.
I tried to find in MySQL docs about what exactly Query Piple up means and how to troubleshoot it further. However, I don't seem to get exact answer in documentation. 
Can someone please explain what exactly is Query Pile up and how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: For debugging a query pileup, this example might be informative: [Anatomy of a query pileup](https://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/anatomy-of-a-query-pileup/116362990932/).

Answer (score 0):

This answer can be foun in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/3.0/en/quan-advisor-ref.html).

> **Query Pileup Advisor**
>
> Alerts when query pileups occur, when the number of threads running
>   increase rapidly over a short period of time. For example, based on
>   the defaults for this advisor, if the exponential moving average of
>   Threads_running has increased by 50% or more, but less than 80%, over
>   the last 1 minute, it raises a Warning alert.
>
> - **Window Size**: duration of the moving average window over which
>     monitoring is done.
> - **Growth Rate Thresholds**: percentage growth rate of the running
>     statements during the defined moving average window.
> - **Minimum Running Threads**: the minimum number of running threads before
>     an event is generated.

I think it's clear enough, isn't it?

Comment: Not clear enough really. What does it mean when Threads_running is increased ? , probably larger number of queries hitting the db ?. But why should that pile up my queries ? How do I troubleshoot what is wrong ?

Comment: if the question is "what is query pileup" i think this is the right answer. It's an advisor for an increasing number of threads. This advisor is just an alert, not a troubleshooting tool, so you should take an analisys to understand what is going wrong.